# Computer won't boot up without a password and I never assigned one

Tags: windows-10

I have this problem but I cannot sign on to my computer, because I have no idea what password windows 10 is looking for, and it will not boot up without one.
K Barbero

Comment: Log into the built in Administrator account, and change the password, to your current user with it

Comment: Or if totally desperate, reformat the machine and restore from a back up

Comment: Might be nitpicking, but it you get the a place where windows asks for a password then it has booted succesfully. Which makes the title misleading/confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up the original administrator account using a Microsoft email address as your MSA (Microsoft Account), which is what I strongly recommend? If so, your logon password is the same as your email password, and this is something you might still remember. You might even have written it down somewhere.

If you did use a Hotmail, Live or Outlook.com account, you have a good chance of getting access to your admin account, by resetting your email account password from the Microsoft Account Password Reset page.